# loop dates and return weeks tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, loops

I am very new in SQL (started just 3 days back) and I got an issue and would hope someone is able to assist me.

I have a query that creates date loops to return me the week number based on the passed in dates. The idea here is to pass loop through the days, months and years and return me a week value. But because of these, I have been getting multiple entries of the same result.

For eg. I am getting:

```
period_wk_key   period_yr_key  period_week  period_week_day  period_week_full_desc
--------------- -------------- ------------ --------------   -----------------------
200001          2000           1             6               2000 WEEK 1
200001          2000           1             6               2000 WEEK 1
200001          2000           1             6               2000 WEEK 1
.               .              .             .               .
200002          2000           2             6               2000 WEEK 2
200002          2000           2             6               2000 WEEK 2
200002          2000           2             6               2000 WEEK 2
.               .              .             .               .    
200003          2000           3             6               2000 WEEK 3
```

each period_wk_key is returning me 7 similar rows which is not what I wanted.

The ideal situation should be:

```
period_wk_key   period_yr_key  period_week  period_week_day  period_week_full_desc
--------------- -------------- ------------ --------------   -----------------------
200001          2000           1             6               2000 WEEK 1
200002          2000           2             6               2000 WEEK 2
200003          2000           3             6               2000 WEEK 3
200004          2000           4             6               2000 WEEK 4
```

I need to know a way to limit the number of output from a loop so that I can have distinct records instead of multiple similar rows. I have attached a code below. It maybe crap to many of you but this is just my 3rd day beginning scripting. Much thanks for any help rendered.

```
    DECLARE @iStartYear INT 
    SET @iStartYear = 2000  
    DECLARE @iEndYear INT
    SET @iEndYear = 2030
    DECLARE @iMth INT
    SET @iMth = 1
    DECLARE @iDay INT
    SET @iDay = 1
    DECLARE @iWeek INT

`DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
WHILE (@iStartYear <= @iEndYear)
   BEGIN
      WHILE (@iMth <= 12)
         BEGIN
      WHILE (@iDay <= DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(m, ((@iStartYear - 1900) * 12) + @iMth - 1, 0)),DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(m, ((@iStartYear - 1900) * 12) + @iMth, 0)))))
              BEGIN `

    SET @iWeek = (DATEPART(dy, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @iStartYear) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @iMth) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @iDay))) - 1) / 7 + 1;

    INSERT INTO dim_period_week (period_wk_key, period_yr_key, period_week, period_week_full_desc,start_date, end_date, period_week_day)
    VALUES (    
    (SELECT CASE WHEN @iWeek < 10 THEN 
        CAST((@iStartYear) AS VARCHAR) + '0' + CAST((@iWeek) AS VARCHAR)
    ELSE
        CAST((@iStartYear) AS VARCHAR)+ CAST((@iWeek) AS VARCHAR)
    END),           
    @iStartYear,
    (SELECT (DATEPART(dy, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @iStartYear) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @iMth) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @iDay))) - 1) / 7 + 1),

    (SELECT CAST((@iStartYear) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + 'WEEK' + ' ' + CAST((@iWeek) AS VARCHAR)),
    (SELECT DATEADD(wk,@iWeek-1, DATEADD(yy,@iStartYear-1900,0))), --START DATE
    (SELECT DATEADD(wk,@iWeek, DATEADD(yy,@iStartYear-1900,0)) -1), --END DATE
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(wk,@iWeek-1, DATEADD(yy,@iStartYear-1900,0)), DATEADD(wk,@iWeek, DATEADD(yy,@iStartYear-1900,0)) -1))
)                           
    `SET @iDay = @iDay + 1 
    END             
    SET @iDay = 1
    SET @iMth = @iMth + 1
    END
    SET @iMth = 1
    SET @iStartYear = @iStartYear + 1
    END
`
```

Comment: An important thing to understand about SQL is NOT to think in terms of loops. Think in terms of data sets.

Comment: Please explain your inputs and ouptuts. In what way does `DATEPART(wk,GETDATE())` not fulfill your needs? I am 99% you are 'doing it wrong' but you are to be commended for making a great effort, which is much more than can be said for most other posters.

Comment: hi.. the reason im not using getdate() is because by doing that, it will only return the week based on current date, which is not what i intended. my table is blank, without any data. I am writing a query to insert date values (ranging year 2000 - 2030) through loops, and from these, extracting the weeks. I managed to do it somehow, but the only problem is I am getting multiple entries, which I believe it might got to do something with the 'Days' loop.

Comment: When I ran your code, I noticed a few dates missing.  For example, there is no entry for 12-31-2027 or 12-31-2029

Answer (score 0):

You are looping every day, but never storing at the day level, so you are doing 7 times as many INSERTs as needed.  Add the following just above your INSERT statement

```
IF DATEPART(weekday, CAST(CAST(@iStartYear * 10000 + @iMth * 100 + @iDay AS VARCHAR(8)) AS datetime)) = 1
INSERT INTO dim_period_week ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a set based approach using a numbers table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Numbers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Numbers
GO
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '20000101'
SELECT 
    (a.Number * 256) + b.Number AS Number
INTO #Numbers
FROM 
    (SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE type = 'P' AND number <= 255) a (Number),
    (SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE type = 'P' AND number <= 255) b (Number)
WHERE 
  (a.Number * 256) + b.Number BETWEEN 0 AND 1617

SELECT 
  WeekKey   = CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)) * 100 + DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)) AS VARCHAR(10)),
  TheYear   = YEAR(DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)),
  TheWeek   = DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)),
  TheWeekDay= DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)),
  WeekDetail= DATENAME(year, DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)) + ' WEEK ' + DATENAME(week, DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate)),
  StartDate = DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate),
  EndDate   = DATEADD(day, 6, DATEADD(day, N.Number * 7, @startDate))
FROM #Numbers N 
ORDER BY 1
```